# Local nameserver issues

Tags: networking, dns

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server that runs a DHCP server for a wired and wireless network and acts as a gateway to the internet (so PCs on the LAN have to connect to the server to access the internet). From PCs on the wired network, I can enter the server's hostname into a browser's address bar and development versions of websites that the server hosts are accessible. If I try the same thing with a PC that's on the wireless network, the server's hostname isn't resolved correctly so the website isn't displayed. PCs on either the wired or wireless network can access sites that are on the internet without any problems. Using "ping " on PCs on the wired network runs without errors but from PCs on the wireless network it fails to resolve the name. Any ideas why the DNS lookup is not working on the WiFi but working OK on the wired interfaces?

EDIT:
I'm using dnsmasq for dns lookups / dhcp control and netplan using NetworkManager for the network configuration (the wireless is set up to act as an access point for any device).

EDIT - in response to PEdroArthur's comment:
dig when run on server:-

> ; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> thincontroller
>   ;; global options: +cmd
>   ;; Got answer:
>   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59068
>   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
>
> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
>   ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
>   ;; QUESTION SECTION:
>   ;thincontroller.                        IN      A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
>   thincontroller.         0       IN      A       127.0.0.1
>   thincontroller.         0       IN      A       127.0.1.1
>   thincontroller.         0       IN      A       192.168.1.254
>   thincontroller.         0       IN      A       10.42.0.254
>
> ;; Query time: 0 msec
>   ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
>   ;; WHEN: Sat Mar 09 11:44:50 GMT 2019
>   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107

And on a PC connected wirelessly:-

> ; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> thincontroller
>   ;; global options: +cmd
>   ;; Got answer:
>   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 33715
>   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
>
> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
>   ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
>   ;; QUESTION SECTION:
>   ;thincontroller.           IN  A
>
> ;; Query time: 0 msec
>   ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
>   ;; WHEN: Sat Mar 09 11:56:07 GMT 2019
>   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43

Comment: What DNS server are you running? Is there an option to keep wireless clients from reaching local IP addresses?

Comment: @heynnema: I haven't configured anything to stop wireless clients from reaching local IP addresses, entering the server's IP address into the address bar rather than the server name works fine on the wireless network, it's just not converting the name to an IP address which it does do on the wired network without any problems.

Comment: can you post the output of `dig hostname` in both machines?